# install apk fails: Finsky POTENTIALLY_UNWANTED

Tags: android, installation, apk

I am developing an android app and ran into some obscure error:
I built a debug apk in the past and installed it on some devices, which worked fine.
Now I wanted to switch to release builds and I can't install them on some of the devices.
I know that switching debug to release can cause problems because of different signing keys, but I uninstalled the app before attemping to install the release version and even tried to clear storage of google play, which solved it for some devices but not for all.
The install dialog only says "App not installed" with no explanation why.
Looking aut logcat I see entries like this:

```
03-20 21:17:03.885 7872-7921/? I/Finsky: [519] ixg.a(8): Not entering foreground
03-20 21:17:03.886 7872-7921/? I/Finsky: [519] uhy.b(3): Verification id=11 response=POTENTIALLY_UNWANTED
03-20 21:17:04.024 7872-7895/? I/Finsky: [494] uhy.b(3): Verification id=11 response=POTENTIALLY_UNWANTED
03-20 21:17:04.033 7872-7921/? I/Finsky: [519] uir.c(3): Verifying id=11, result=-1
03-20 21:17:04.043 1913-5139/? I/ActivityManager: START u0 {dat=file:///data/user_de/0/com.google.android.packageinstaller/no_backup/package4125719949464292501.apk flg=0x2000000 cmp=com.google.android.packageinstaller/com.android.packageinstaller.InstallFailed (has extras)} from uid 10015
03-20 21:17:04.043 7872-7921/? I/Finsky: [519] uhq.a(19): Installation silently blocked for <removed>
03-20 21:17:04.044 7872-7872/? I/Finsky: [2] uir.b(6): Verification complete: id=11, package_name=<removed>
03-20 21:17:04.055 6785-10144/? I/ApkUploadChimeraService: Adding apk for upload: <removed>:1100
03-20 21:17:04.062 4363-4363/? W/ActivityThread: handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy@3700482
03-20 21:17:04.069 4363-4363/? D/InstallFailed: Installation status code: 1
```

I'm out of ideas, how can I get the release apk to install?

Also I don't understand why it tells me POTENTIALLY_UNWANTED, what more intention than opening an apk and clicking INSTALL does it need?

Also the app is absolutly fine (i.e. no virus, backdoor, whatever, and it only requires INTERNET privileges).

In order to install the app, I followed the following steps:

- Build signed APK in intellij idea (Release mode, both v1 and v2 signatures)
- Copy apk to phone using a web server (I.e. download using chrome on phone)
- Click apk in phone file browser/Chrome downloads
- Enable untrusted sources for this installation
- Click install.

After which the phone is working for some time and then fails with "App not installed" and no further information anywhere.

Comment: Updated the question

Answer (score 1):

It may have been caused by the Google Play updates. 
Disable `Play Protect` & then try to install the app.

**Steps :**

1. Go to `Google Play -> Play Protect`.
2. Turn off `Scanning device for security threats`.